# Is OSMDroid trying to open and render a cached map tile it downloaded?

Tags: android, kotlin, osmdroid

### Context

I am developing an app that uses OSMDroid. While running the map functionality and testing for bugs, I stumble across something like this in the logs:

```
...
2023-02-17 15:19:06.820 28041-28422 .networkmonitor         com.project123.networkmonitor        E  Failed to open file '/data/data/com.project123.networkmonitor/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/17/109600/60180.png': No such file or directory
2023-02-17 15:19:06.820 28041-28422 .networkmonitor         com.project123.networkmonitor        E  Failed to open file '/data/data/com.project123.networkmonitor/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/17/109600/60180.png': No such file or directory
2023-02-17 15:19:06.823 28041-28422 .networkmonitor         com.project123.networkmonitor        E  Failed to open file '/data/data/com.project123.networkmonitor/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/17/109594/60181.png': No such file or directory
2023-02-17 15:19:06.823 28041-28422 .networkmonitor         com.project123.networkmonitor        E  Failed to open file '/data/data/com.project123.networkmonitor/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/17/109594/60181.png': No such file or directory
2023-02-17 15:19:06.826 28041-28422 .networkmonitor         com.project123.networkmonitor        E  Failed to open file '/data/data/com.project123.networkmonitor/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/17/109595/60181.png': No such file or directory
2023-02-17 15:19:06.826 28041-28422 .networkmonitor         com.project123.networkmonitor        E  Failed to open file '/data/data/com.project123.networkmonitor/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/17/109595/60181.png': No such file or directory
2023-02-17 15:19:06.828 28041-28422 .networkmonitor         com.project123.networkmonitor        E  Failed to open file '/data/data/com.project123.networkmonitor/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/17/109596/60181.png': No such file or directory
2023-02-17 15:19:06.828 28041-28422 .networkmonitor         com.project123.networkmonitor        E  Failed to open file '/data/data/com.project123.networkmonitor/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/Mapnik/17/109596/60181.png': No such file or directory
...
```

And it would continue to go on like this until I exit the activity running the Map. It wasn't app-breaking, but it is kind of annoying since I've been trying to find a way to get rid of the message.

After some research, I figured that it might have something to do with how map tiles are cached but I have no idea where to look for the root cause. Additionally, the map tiles are rendered correctly.

So I looked for anything related to the problem, and got this part of the code:

```kotlin
...
val tileSource: ITileSource =
    XYTileSource(
        "Mapnik", 1, 18, 256, ".png",
        arrayOf<String>(
            // extra URLs
            //"https://tiles.wmflabs.org/hikebike/"
            "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/"
        )
    )
osmDroidMapView.setTileSource(tileSource)
...
```

Since this is the only part of the code where "Mapnik" is mentioned, I figured I dive right into TileSource's implementation. TileSource could point me to where the error is being produced, but nothing (yet) turned up.

### Question

- Though the map tiles are loaded properly, why does something like this happen to OSMDroid? Is it trying to access and rendered the cached map tiles it downloaded?
- If it was downloaded, why doesn't the cache and its directory exist? Should it exist somewhere? I did try to look for the files it tried to access, but haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

Same error occured to me when i lowered minSDK from 26 to 24. Raising minSDK back to 26 resolved issue.